# mvc display text after post and keep data in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

How can I after posting a form in my mvc page display a message and keeping the added/selected data in the form? I have tried to render a partialview but that renders a blank page which only contains the actual partialview.

```
<div id="resultTarget">
    @Html.Partial("CalculationResult", new Model.CalculatedPrice())
</div>

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult GetPrice(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    // This renders only the partialview
    return PartialView("CalculationResult", model);
}
```

Comment: What would I return in the GetPrice then? If I just use return View(); I get an error telling me "The view 'GetPrice' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations"

Comment: `[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult GetPrice(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    ViewBag.Test = "message";
    return PartialView("CalculationResult", model);
}`  Then in your "CalculationResult" view.. put @ViewBag.Test wherever you want the message to go

Comment: When I try that I come to a blank page after post just showing the actual viewbag message. That cant be right,...

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that you can access the Viewbag in the CalculationResult view.. but the data isn't there?

Comment: The viewbag message is displayed on the page, but that is the only thing displayed, everything else that is there from the beginning (form, form fields, images etc) is gone..

Comment: Okay, have you looked into creating a ViewModel?

Comment: Is that a requirement for this to work. It seem like a trivial thing to do...

Answer (score 1):

If you reload the page with a form post the data will be lost. Create a view model and bind the controls to specific properties using `@Html.TextBoxFor()`, `@Html.ListBoxFor()` etc.

Now instead of submitting the form back to the controller, use javascript to post data back to the controller on a button click function.

See below code :

**In Button Click function :**

```
var modelObj = {};
modelObj.prop1 = $('#txtField1').val();
modelObj.prop2 = $('#txtField2').val();
var postObj = JSON.stringify(modelObj); // convert object to json

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
traditional: true,
dataType: "json",
url: "/SomeController/GetPrice",
data: { formCollection: postObj }
cache: false,
success: function (data) {
    if (data) {
        //Some Code if post success
    }
    else {
        // Some code if post failed
    }
}});
```

**In SomeController :**

```
[HttpPost]
public JSonResult GetPrice(FormCollection formCollection)
{
// Do your action with the formCollection object here
// if(action.success)
   {
        return JSon(true);
   }
   return JSon(false);
}
```

This way you can prevent reloading of the page and keep the data in the forms as such.